# Efficient Randomizer for Wordpress Data Query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, random

I found the following mysql randomizer but can't seem to grasp the syntax to apply to my code.  The randomizer is:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  @cnt := COUNT(*) + 1,
                @lim := 10
        FROM    t_random
        ) vars
STRAIGHT_JOIN
        (
        SELECT  r.*,
                @lim := @lim - 1
        FROM    t_random r
        WHERE   (@cnt := @cnt - 1)
                AND RAND(20090301) < @lim / @cnt
        )
```

I need to apply it to a wordpress mysql query.

```
$query = "
        SELECT ID from $wpdb->posts p
        JOIN $wpdb->postmeta meta1 ON meta1.post_id = p.ID
        WHERE p.post_status = $post_status
        AND p.post_type = $post_type
        AND meta1.meta_key = 'gallery'
        AND meta1.meta_value = '$gallery'";
```

Comment: why not just use "ORDER BY RAND()", and why not use `$wpdb->get_results()` and avoid writing your own SQL?

Comment: ORDER BY RAND() is not very efficient.  I do use $wpdb->get_col() to get the informatin i need after randomized.